# Check out file, but then ignore any changes made, don't include it with svn commit or svn status?

Tags: eclipse, svn

We have our Eclipse .classpath and .project (among others) in our SVN repository. I really don't want SVN reminding me that I've updated the file. I never want to check in this file. I just want SVN to forget I have checked it out, and leave me alone. Is this possible? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVN:ignore how-to and on what?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344227/svnignore-how-to-and-on-what)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing I do when I create an Eclipse project hooked up to Subversion is svn:ignore the .classpath and .project file. Since you've already done this, I would just remove them from your svn, and THEN ignore them. There's no reason for them to be in there, honestly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is an official way.

However you can add both files to svn:ignore.

Name the checked in files txt.classpath and txt.project. Copy them to the correct names after checkout.